# Django ORM DB Query Optimization

Tags: django, django-models, orm, query-optimization, django-queryset

I have a Query that consists of two DB hits.
which the first contains 'aggregate' - so it perform immediately.
I want to know if I can reduce it to only one DB hit.

The query is:
"Find customers that their id's numbers are bigger than all of texas's customers id's."

The two querysets are:

```
highest_tx_id = Customer.objects.filter(state='TX').aggregate(Max('id'))
res = Customer.objects.filter(id__gt=highest_tx_id['id_max'])
```

Adding an example:

```js
>>> reset_queries()
>>> highest_tx_id = Customer.objects.filter(state='TX').aggregate(Max('id'))
>>> res = Customer.objects.filter(id__gt=highest_tx_id['id__max'])
>>> connection.queries
[{'sql': 'SELECT MAX("customer"."id") AS "id__max" FROM "customer" WHERE "customer"."state" = \'TX\'', 'time': '0.001'}]
>>> res
<QuerySet [<Customer: Customer object (550)>, <Customer: Customer object (551)>, <Customer: Customer object (552)>, <Customer: Customer object (553)>, <Customer: Customer object (555)>, <Customer: Customer object (661)>, <Customer: Customer object (665)>]>
>>> connection.queries
[{'sql': 'SELECT MAX("customer"."id") AS "id__max" FROM "customer" WHERE "customer"."state" = \'TX\'', 'time': '0.001'}, {'sql': 'SELECT "customer"."id", "customer"."fname", "customer"."lname", "customer"."address", "customer"."city", "customer"."state", "customer"."zip_code", "customer"."phone", "customer"."company_name" FROM "customer" WHERE "customer"."id" > 444 LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.001'}]      
>>>
```

Any way to do these type of queries using 1 DB hit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building up on @TaipanRex's answer, you can do something like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery

highest_tx_id = Customer.objects.filter(state='TX').order_by('-id').values('id')[:1]
res = Customer.objects.filter(id__gt=Subquery(highest_tx_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression).

```
from django.db.models import Subquery
highest_tx_id = Customer.objects.filter(state='TX').aggregate(Max('id'))['id__max']
res = Customer.objects.filter(id__gt=Subquery(highest_tx_id))
```

Comment: Tried something like that. The first query hits the DB (I think because the aggregate).
The second query yields an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'query'..